# How to concat fullname with extension name?

Tags: mysql

I want to make a view that will concatenate the fullname of the user. If the user has extension name it will concatenate it with the fullname.

For example:

> John May Brown(Fname,Mname,Lname)

with extension name

> John May Brown Jr.(Fname,Mname,Lname,ExtName)

My code:

```
Create view viewforum (
  SELECT A.*, CONCAT(B.Fname," ",B.Mname," ",B.Lname," ",B.ExtName) AS Fullname
  FROM forum_table A INNER JOIN user_table B
  WHERE A.user_id = B.user_id
);
```

Output:

All of the data under the column Fullname is `NULL` because some user information doesn't have extension name on it. So the output is `NULL`.

How can I make condition on it?

Comment: A side note: your join condition should be using explicit joins as: `FROM forum_table A INNER JOIN user_table B ON A.user_id = B.user_id`. The syntax `FROM forum_table A, user_table B WHERE A.user_id = B.user_id` is older and shouldn't be used anymore. In any case you shouldn't mix the two.

Comment: See CONCAT_WS() - and you would want an OUTER JOIN here.

Comment: Thanks for advise. I will rather do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more complex in order to eliminate the `nulls`:

```
Create view viewforum (SELECT A.*, 
   CONCAT(
        B.Fname,
        " ",
        COALESCE(B.Mname, ""),
        " ",
        B.Lname," ",
        COALESCE(B.ExtName,"")
   ) AS Fullname FROM forum_table A INNER JOIN user_table B WHERE A.user_id = B.user_id);
```

`COALESCE` will pick the first not null value from the list of values. So `COALESCE(B.ExtName, "")` will result in an empty string if `B.ExtName`is `Null`

Comment: Thanks sir axel i appreciate your effort. Have a great day. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use IFNULL to handle null values

```
Create view viewforum 
(  SELECT A.*, CONCAT(IFNULL(B.Fname," "),"  ",IFNULL(B.Mname," ")," ",IFNULL(B.Lname," ")," ",IFNULL(B.ExtName," ")) AS Fullname
FROM forum_table A INNER JOIN user_table B
WHERE A.user_id = B.user_id
);
```

Will return you the required result without null issue